# How do I calculate an unbiased estimate of the standard deviation, knowing only the degrees of freedom

Tags: standard-deviation, range

I have $k$ groups of $m$ independent samples from a standard normal distribution. The groups are averaged as $K_1$ through $K_m$ the total number of samples is then $mk=n$. I also have the range of $K_{\text{max}} - K_{\text{min}} = w$. What is the best way to estimate the standard deviation?

Should I use $s=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$?

Comment: I would estimate the SD as $1$, because we are assuming it equals $1$.

Comment: It looks like a Chi Squared distribution might be the way to go. A student-t distribution is constructed by assuming picks from a normal distribution, having a standard deviation which follows a chi squared distribution.

Comment: OK, I guess my first comment was too subtle.  By definition, the value of $s$ for a "standard normal distribution" is $1$.  Therefore you don't have to estimate anything.  What, then, is your question really about?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to calculate critical values for the studentized range distribution, and this requires an estimate of s. Sources on how the distribution arises have been spotty, especially where the s estimate comes from. It doesn't help that some of the tables online have slightly different values.